# How to map values with a key to a column in a Spark DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, feature-engineering

I am doing some feature engineering in Spark 2.3 with Scala.

I have IP addresses in a column of a Spark DataFrame looking like

[[image: IP Column Example].](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVq2R.png)

I then used `data.groupBy("ip").count()` to get a list of frequencies for each IP address. This looks like

[image: IP Count Frequencies]

Now I want to map each of those frequencies to the original dataframe. Where I would have

```
ip  | freq |
--  |      |
123 | 3    |
567 | 7    |
857 | 10   |
123 | 3    |
```

What would be an efficient way of solving such a problem ?

Comment: left join with the original

Comment: Wow! I've been busting my head and failed so see that. Thank you so much

Comment: so you sorted it out right?

Comment: I did data.join(freq_map, Seq("ip"), joinType="outer")) and worked beautifully!

Comment: great to hear that :)

Answer (score 0):

I develop pipelines with 1billion+ rows and this is how I'd go about this.

w = Window.partitionBy('id')

df.withColumn('freq', F.count('id').over(w) ).show()

This is much simpler, reads well, and most importantly efficient. It doesn't aggregate data so no need for creating two df objects and joining.

The previous answer doesn't scale up well with big data, primarily as joins are expensive due to the extra shuffles.